# Deleting duplicate text in Applescript

Tags: text, applescript, duplicates

### Applescript: Deleting Duplicates in a text file

I have a .txt file which I've created, and I'm trying to delete certain lines of text which are duplicates.

The name I've given the file is today.txt, located on my desktop, and it contains a list of URLs for the NYtimes Today's Paper. However, through parsing an html file, I receive several urls that are duplicates, like so:

```
http://www.nytimes.com/2012/07/06/education/no-child-left-behind-whittled-down-under-obama.html
http://www.nytimes.com/2012/07/06/business/global/markets-look-to-europes-central-bank-for-action.html
http://www.nytimes.com/2012/07/06/business/global/markets-look-to-europes-central-bank-for-action.html
http://www.nytimes.com/2012/07/06/nyregion/3-children-killed-in-long-island-boating-accident.html
http://www.nytimes.com/2012/07/06/nyregion/3-children-killed-in-long-island-boating-accident.html
http://www.nytimes.com/2012/07/06/world/americas/earthquake-relief-where-haiti-wasnt-broken.html
http://www.nytimes.com/2012/07/06/world/americas/earthquake-relief-where-haiti-wasnt-broken.html
http://www.nytimes.com/2012/07/06/us/politics/journal-critique-of-romney-shows-murdoch-doubt-on-candidacy.html
http://www.nytimes.com/2012/07/06/us/politics/journal-critique-of-romney-shows-murdoch-doubt-on-candidacy.html
http://www.nytimes.com/2012/07/06/technology/at-hacker-hostels-living-on-the-cheap-and-dreaming-of-digital-glory.html
http://www.nytimes.com/2012/07/06/technology/at-hacker-hostels-living-on-the-cheap-and-dreaming-of-digital-glory.html
```

I've been trying to remove the duplicates through a *do shell script* in Applescript, but I haven't been able to make it work. Here is my code:

```
set delDups to do shell script "sort /Users/paolob/Desktop/today.txt | uniq -u"
return delDups
```

**So my question**:
How can I delete the duplicates in my *today.txt* file,
and then save the result to the same *today.txt* file

Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you in advance.

**Edit**
It would be more economical and faster if in fact the shell script, or whatever duplicate deleter you suggest, reads the text directly in Applescript Editor, and then sets the new text to a *new_text* variable, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
set filePath to (path to desktop as text) & "today.txt"
set theText to read file filePath
set textList to paragraphs of theText

set uniqueList to {}
repeat with i from 1 to count of textList
    set thisParagraph to item i of textList
    if thisParagraph is not in uniqueList then set end of uniqueList to thisParagraph
end repeat

set {tids, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, return}
set uniqueText to uniqueList as text
set text item delimiters to tids

set openFile to open for access file filePath with write permission
set eof of openFile to 0
write uniqueText to openFile starting at eof as text
close access openFile
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using only shell scripting. You really don't need any applescript, unless it's part of a bigger program.

The following will sort and enforce uniqueness and save it back to the same file.

```
sort -u -o /Users/paolob/Desktop/today.txt /Users/paolob/Desktop/today.txt
```

This can be wrapped with applescript like so :

```
do shell script "sort -u -o /Users/paolob/Desktop/today.txt /Users/paolob/Desktop/today.txt"
```

If you wanted to do more processing after hand something like this would work :

```
set myText to do shell script "sort -u /Users/paolob/Desktop/today.txt"
```

Comment: It seems this is not working. The filepath is correct, and the script runs, but the duplicates still exist. I know that this shell script works because I've used it before (in a different case), but when I run it in terminal, it doesn't work either.
`sort -u` works, but not `sort -o`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in ruby. open up 'irb' from the terminal in the folder with your file and do the following in the interactive shell:

> > file = File.new("test.txt", 'r') #This opens "test.txt" (substitute your own file name)
> >
> > array = [] #creates a new array.
> >
> > file.lines.each{|k| array << k.to_s} #put the lines from the file in the array
> >
> > array.uniq! #make those lines unique
> >
> > File.open("outfile.txt", "w"){|file| s = String.new(); array.each{|k| s << k}; file.puts(s)} # creates an file (outfile.txt) and writes the unique lines to the file
> >
> > exit #closes irb